# What functions are solution to a homogeneous system of differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a vector $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For what functions $\psi(t)$ can $\vec{x}(t) = \psi(t)\vec{u}$ be a solution of $\dot{\vec{x}} = A \vec{x}$ for some $n \times n$ matrix $A$?

I'm trying to prove that $\psi(t)$ has to be of the form $e^{\lambda t}$ for some constant $\lambda$, but I'm not sure about that and I do not know exactly how to prove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$\dot \psi u= A \psi u$$

Suppose that $\psi(t_0)\neq0$ for some $t_0$. Then by continuity, in some neighbourhood

$$ A u = \frac{\dot\psi}\psi u$$

(and hence $\dot \psi/\psi$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ assuming $u\neq0$.) But the left-hand side is a constant; therefore so is the other, and the result follows.

Comment: The fraction cannot switch continuously between different values since the right-hand side of
$$ A u = \frac{\dot\psi}\psi u$$
is constant. It follows that $\frac{\dot\psi}\psi$ is constant and therefore, $\psi(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ for some $\lambda$, right?

Comment: Indeed! I've simplified that statement to make it clearer.

Comment: I meant left-hand side, of course. Thank you!